# Can a logic app or function be triggered when a blob is scanned by Azure Advanced Threat Protection

Tags: azure, security, azure-blob-storage

Is it possible to capture each time advanced threat protection scans a blob in azure storage? I am aware of that ATP will create an alert in security center if the blob is detected as malware. However, it is hard to know if a blob has been scanned and not been flagged as malware.

What i am looking for is a way to mark the blobs which have passed the malware scan done by ATP.

Help is appreciated
Regards

Answer (score 1):

At the moment, there is no such trigger for blob. You can use Azure security center or Azure Sentinel to create alert or incident and those services can invoke logic app for certain conditions

Comment: Not sure how to create a custom alert which is triggered when a blob is scanned by ATP.

Comment: I am not sure either. there is a long pending task for storage team on anti malware scanning for blob - https://feedback.azure.com/forums/217298-storage/suggestions/6731289-azure-antimalware-should-be-able-to-scan-blob-stor. Not sure if you are looking for something similar.